# Java gui does not print after action listeners listens to event

Tags: java, user-interface

Code does not output the "Works" message in the ide text field. How can I make it so the program outputs in the ide's text my message? Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends JFrame {

    private JButton button1;

    public test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Program");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me PLEASE!");
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.add(button1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        Listener1 listen = new Listener1();
        button1.addActionListener(listen);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

    private class Listener1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == button1) {
                System.out.println("Works!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of `button1` you are comparing with is not the instance of `button1` which triggered the event...

Basically, you are shadowing your variables...

```
// Declare instance variable here...
private JButton button1;

public test() {
    //...
    // Redeclared as local variable here
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me PLEASE!");
```

If you add...

```
System.out.println("button1 = " + button1);
```

to you `Listener1`, you will find that it is `null`

Remove the local declaration...

```
    button1 = new JButton("Click me PLEASE!");
```

Comment: If I remove the local declaration, I can't use the button1 in test() method. I am sure there must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: I get this after removing the local declaration:

Comment: @user3562855: I would recommend that you listen to mad's recs and follow them as he's right.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1090)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
 at test.<init>(test.java:24)
 at test.main(test.java:35)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @user3562855 Sounds like you're not initialising the button, but, instead, have remove the entire line, instead of removing the `JButton` declaration...

Comment: @user3562855 Welcome to my club :P